# Display data into HTML table PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am retrieving data from MySQl data base and displaying it into HTML table and it works fine.
For each row i have a Button that when Clicking on it displays the details of the current row.
This is working fine for all rows expect the first row, when i click on the button "edit" it does'nt redirect me to the details page.

Please help! 
[This is the index page with the list of persons :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2S4QS.png)

This is the code of displaying the list of persons and  redirect to the page "edit" when click on "edit" button

```html
<table border = 1> 
 <caption> Liste des personnes </caption> 
  <tr><th>id </th><th>nom</th><th>prenom</th><th>date Naissance</th><th>sexe</th><th>ville</th><th>comptence</th><th>photo</th></tr>
    <?php
    while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
    ?> 
    <tr ><td> <?= $obj->id ?> </td><td><?= $obj->nom?></td><td><?= $obj->prenom?></td><td><?= $obj->dateNaissance?></td>
    <td><?= $obj->sexe?></td><td><?= $obj->ville?></td> <td><?= $obj->competence?></td>
   
     <?php 
    if (isset($obj->photo)) {?>
    <td><img src="uploads/<?= $obj->photo?>" width =20 height = 20 >
    <?php 
      }
    ?>
    <td>
        <form name="editPerson" action="edit.php" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=  $obj->id  ?>">
            <input type="submit" name="editer" value="Edit">
        </form>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        }
    ?>
 </table>
```

Comment: What is the generated HTML? You never close the `td` for the image.

Comment: Wired, because something must happen when you click the first edit button, no matter what value is given, the form must load edit.php on click. Any other fancy javasrcipt running?

Comment: maybe your editing mysql's failing; could be anything and there's no redirection here

Comment: also, `<form>` cannot be child of `<table>`

Comment: A: you need to debug

Comment: It works for all the rows : I mean i have another page edit.php will be loaded every time i click on the button "edit": the problem is it does'nt work for the first row only! it works for all rows except the first one

Answer (score 1):

first for displaying data in your table rows you should echo out.
when click the edit button you can pass the data through GET method to details page.
`<a href="details.php?id=".$obj->id">edit </a>`

in `details.php` page get the id by `$_GET['id']` ..search the row which `id = $_GET['id']` and by fetch assoc function to load the values to input field.
eg:

```
<input value="<?php echo $obj->nom;?>" name="nom">
```

Comment: Thanks you for replying.

Comment: I have displayed data into the table with success. And the click on  the details button work too but not for the firt row (it displays details of all the table rows except the first row)